# Can I exchange my Texas driving license for an Italian license

Tags: driving-license, italy

Can I exchange a Texas license for an Italian license. When I lived in France some states you could.

If not, what if I just drive/ride using my Texas license for several years....

Comment: Individual states do not have the ability to enter in to agreements with sovereign nations.  It's entirely up to the host country to do it or not

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not.

From the [US Embassy in Italy](http://italy.usembassy.gov/acs/general-driving.html):

> **Unfortunately, there is no agreement for reciprocal recognition of drivers' licenses between the United States and Italy**. The Italian Ministry of Transportation has determined that bearers of U.S. driver's licenses cannot obtain an Italian license directly in exchange for a domestic one. Interested individuals must comply with the usual requirements prescribed for obtaining an Italian license, (a written test, a driving test, a medical examination, and pertinent documents).